# Change lib folder when clear and build

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

When I "clear and build" a project in Netbeans creates a folder called "dist" with the jar and another folder into called "lib" with the external jars. Can I change "lib" for another name in Netbeans's configuration? I could change the manifest of main jar but I do not want do that every time that i compile.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dist library directory name is hard-coded, unfortunately. See the source code for the relevant ant task:

http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/62bea1ba5c94/java.j2seproject/copylibstask/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/CopyLibs.java#l212

You might be able to rename the folder afterwards and then pull out the rebasing code into your own custom ant task to modify the manifest.